# ~80s novel about WW3, space station, space shuttle

Tags: story-identification, novel

I was wondering if anyone could help me with a title and author for a vintage book (early 1980s) in which a bunch of astronauts are onboard a space station when World War III happens.  I think in one part they attempt to land on Earth with a space shuttle, there's discussion of repopulation, and I believe they try to extract seeds from feces.  Yeah, I know those are weird details, but it's what I recall. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm very interested in the answer to this too.

Answer (score 7):

**Earthwreck!** by Thomas N. Scortia (1974)

A US and a Soviet space station hold the only living humans after a terrorist attack in the middle east sparks global nuclear war. Except for one person on the ground at Cape Canaveral.

The US crew goes through the crew's feces to find fertile seeds. The Soviets hatch their fertile chicken eggs (captain loves the blood taste of fertile eggs).

The two stations have barely enough resources combined to establish a tiny Mars colony, and wait for the radioactive Earth to cool off. But the US and Soviet crews are deeply suspicious of each other

Comment: Awesome, thanks.